# How to get cell data from Excel file using Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-excel

I use the Microsoft Graph SDK and try to read the content of an Excel file within a MS Teams Channel.

I am able to retrieve the UsedRange of the worksheet that I want to read from. I do this with the following call:

```
var usedRangeWorksheetDetails = await _graphServiceClient
    .Drives[teamsChannelDriveId]
    .Items[driveItemExcelFile.Id]
    .Workbook
    .Worksheets["Details"]
    .UsedRange
    .GetAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When I inspect the UsedRange object returned from this call in the debugger, I see it correctly identified the cells that hold values, e.g. it shows a column count of 45 and a row count of 25, and the address of the range is `Details!A1:AS25`

How do I get from here to the actual cell data? I see a property called **Values** which is of type `Microsoft.Graph.Models.Json` but I have no idea how to use this.

If I run the equivalent of my SDK call in the Graph Explorer with the following URL:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[teamsChannelDriveId]/items/[driveItemExcelFileId]/workbook/worksheets/Details/UsedRange](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%5BteamsChannelDriveId%5D/items/%5BdriveItemExcelFileId%5D/workbook/worksheets/Details/UsedRange) and look in the Response Preview I see a JSON including a field called `values` that holds the cell data. So I expect the same must be possible using the SDK, but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is the main issue in SDK v5 for almost one year. Code for SDK is auto-generated, but the generator doesn't have support for untyped JSON represented by `Microsoft.Graph.Models.Json`.

Currently, an enhancement is in progress, but no exact ETA.

Issues:

https://github.com/microsoft/kiota/issues/2319

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1783

https://github.com/microsoft/kiota/issues/3007

You can try to read all discussions on GitHub, maybe there will be some workaround mentioned. If you can, leave a comment on GitHub, so the Graph team is motivated to resolve it.